# Trying to customize the Django SetPasswordForm

Tags: python, django

I was trying to overwrite SetPasswordForm to add a placeholder and a class but it seems that it is not working. I managed to do it for login page and password reset page but here I got stuck.

```css
class MySetPasswordForm(SetPasswordForm):
    new_password1 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("New password"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'New Password', 'class': 'password1'}),
        strip=False,
        help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html(),
    )
    new_password2 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("New password confirmation"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Repeat Password', 'class': 'password2'}),
    )
```

```html
urlpatterns = [  path('accounts/password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
                      form_class=MyPasswordResetForm)),
                  path('accounts/password_reset_confirm/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
                      form_class=MySetPasswordForm)),
                  path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),]
```

Is this accurate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re using the wrong path in your URL patterns. It should be:

```
'reset/<uidb64>/<token>/'
```

Comment: You can see it in the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#using-the-views), or you can look at [`django.contrib.auth.urls`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/urls.py)

Answer (score 0):

> **Override or customize the django auth setPasswordFrom and
> PasswordResetForm**, answer already give but without using path() in
> django url i.e django 1.11 I have done in below ways. Copy the
> setPasswordFrom form folder structure django.contrib.auth.forms import
> SetPasswordForm.
>
> In urls.py

```
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
    from GetAdmin360.forms import (EmailValidationOnForgotPassword, CustomSetPasswordForm)

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(form_class = CustomSetPasswordForm), {'template_name': 'registration/password_reset_confirm.html'}, name='password_reset_confirm'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

> In forms.py in which I have override the setPasswordFrom and
> PasswordResetForm

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import (PasswordResetForm, SetPasswordForm)
from MyApp.models import MyUser

class EmailValidationOnForgotPassword(PasswordResetForm):
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if not MyUser.objects.filter(email__iexact=email, is_active=True).exists():
            raise ValidationError("The email address you entered is not registered. Please enter registered email id")
        return email


class CustomSetPasswordForm(SetPasswordForm):
    """
    A form that lets a user change set their password without entering the old
    password
    """
    error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': _("The two password fields didn't match."),
        'password_notvalid': _("Password must of 8 Character which contain alphanumeric with atleast 1 special charater and 1 uppercase."),
    }
    new_password1 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("New password"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        strip=False,
        help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html(),
    )
    new_password2 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("New password confirmation"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
    )

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super(SetPasswordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_new_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password2')
        if password1 and password2:
            if password1 != password2:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                    code='password_mismatch',
                )
            # Regix to check the password must contains sepcial char, numbers, char with upeercase and lowercase.
            regex = re.compile('((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{8,30})')
            if(regex.search(password1) == None):
                    raise forms.ValidationError(
                    self.error_messages['password_notvalid'],
                    code='password_mismatch',
                )

        password_validation.validate_password(password2, self.user)
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        password = self.cleaned_data["new_password1"]
        self.user.set_password(password)
        if commit:
            self.user.save()
        email = self.user.email
        instance = MyUser.objects.get(id=self.user.id)
        if not instance.first_login:
            instance.first_login = True
            instance.save()
        return self.user
```